# Exporting dataframe to a specific excel sheet and cell

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am very new to Python and I can't figure this out.
I have created a Dataframe with 3 columns and I have exported this to Excel.
The code that I try to write is that this DataFrame is exporting to a specific sheet and cell in Excel, for example the first cell of the DataFrame is exporting to sheet 5, Cell I5 and the rest of the DataFrame will line up. I have looked in modules like openpyxl and xlsxwriter or maybe it just that simple tot specify the location when you are exporting to excel. I don't know, again I am very new to python. I really hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, instead of just describing what the code you wrote is supposed to do, add the actual code to your question. This way, it is more likely that someone will be able to identify how to help you.

Comment: See here [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html). There is `sheet_name, startrow, startcol`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for the tip, I got it to work, but in the process, it deleted all the other sheets. There are 8 sheets in the excel file and when I exported it, only the sheet where I exported it to is left. Do you know how I can fix this problem? thank you in advance

Comment: Database.to_excel(excelsheet, sheet_name='test', na_rep='Missing', index=False, startrow=3, startcol=14) this is the code that I currently have

Comment: You changed the parameters of the question. You need to include what you really want in your question. To do what you want you will need to use `openpyxl` to open the file, iterate over the sheets and insert the data at the desired column/row insertion point. Though if there is already data in that range it will be overwritten